# Restrict users access specific object

Tags: permissions

I have account which use as 'template' - apex clone this account when needed.
I wish to prevent all the SF users modify this object’s fields.

I'm wondering what would be the best way (would prefer avoid triggers)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this account is a configuration. Maybe move it to custom setting or custom metadata types ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limited options to achieve what you are aiming at. It would be a better practice, as Alexander mentioned in a comment, to encode your template in Custom Settings or a Custom Metadata Type.

If your Org-Wide Default for Account is Private, the easiest solution would be to have this account be owned by a system user and ensure that no sharing rules apply to it.

If the OWD is not Private, your options are substantially more limited. You could create a Validation Rule tied directly to that Account's Id that always fails. However, this will immediately break any broad-based Account updates you perform, and it's a fragile solution.

Comment: Thank you both - custom settings may help if I would need few fields - in my case I wish the 'Account template' to be saved as Account entity, so in would be easy to manage. I guess trigger it is.

Comment: A validation rule can probably achieve this at lower cost than a trigger.

Comment: Sure VR should work either.